# Easy way to implement small buffer optimization for arbitrary type erasure (like in std::function.)

Tags: c++, c++11

I tend to use type erasure technique quite a bit.
It typically looks like this:

```
class YetAnotherTypeErasure
{
public:
   // interface redirected to pImpl
private:
   // Adapting function
   template ...
   friend YetAnotherTypeErasure make_YetAnotherTypeErasure (...);

   class Interface {...};

   template <typename Adaptee>
   class Concrete final : public Interface { 
     // redirecting Interface to Adaptee
   };

   std::unique_ptr<Interface> pImpl_; // always on the heap
};
```

`std::function` does something similar, but it has a small buffer optimization, so if `Concrete<Adaptee>` is smaller than smth and has nothrow move operations, it will be stored in it. Is there some generic library solution to do it fairly easy? For enforcing small buffer only storing at compile time? Maybe something has been proposed for standardisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a reasonably nice solution for everyday code - use std::function

With tiny library support to help with const correctness,
the code get's down to 20 lines:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GtewFI

Answer (score 3):

I know nothing about the small buffer optimization *required* by the standard or any proposal, though it is often allowed or encouraged.

<sub>Note that some (conditionally) non-throwing requirements on such types effectively require the optimization in practice because alternatives (like non-throwing allocation from emergency buffers) seem insane here.</sub>

On the other hand, you can just make your own solution from scratch, based on the standard library (e.g. `std::aligned_storage`). This may still verbose from the view of users, but not too hard.

Actually I implemented (not proposed then) [`any` with such optimization](https://osdn.net/projects/yslib/scm/hg/YSLib/blobs/ca54ab668d0f58df952225b2f5b10420756699a5/YBase/include/ystdex/any.h) and [some related utilities](https://osdn.net/projects/yslib/scm/hg/YSLib/blobs/ca54ab668d0f58df952225b2f5b10420756699a5/YBase/include/ystdex/any_iterator.hpp) several years ago. Lately, libstdc++'s implementation of `std::experimental::any` used the technique almost exactly as this (however, `__` prefixed internal names are certainly not good for ordinary library users).

My implementation now uses [some common helpers](https://osdn.net/projects/yslib/scm/hg/YSLib/blobs/ca54ab668d0f58df952225b2f5b10420756699a5/YBase/include/ystdex/type_pun.hpp) to deal with the storage. These helpers do ease to implement the type erasure storage strategy (at least fit for something similar to `any` enough). But I am still interested in more general high-level solution to simplify the interface redirecting.

There is also [a `function` implementation](https://osdn.net/projects/yslib/scm/hg/YSLib/blobs/ca54ab668d0f58df952225b2f5b10420756699a5/YBase/include/ystdex/function.hpp) based directly on the `any` implementation above. They support move-only types and sane allocator interface, while `std` ones not. The `function` implementation has better performance than `std::function` in libstdc++ in some cases, thanks to the (partially no-op) default initialization of the underlying `any` object.

Comment: Are these links no longer working? I get "That link has no power here" when following them.

Comment: @LouisLangholtz Bitbucket stopped the Mercurial support last year. I've fixed the links.

Answer (score 1):

I think C++20 polymorphic_value comes closest to what we can do in modern c++: [wg21.link/p0201](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0201r5.html)

Basically it's like std::any but all of your types have to inherit the same interface.
It is Semiregular, they decided to drop equality.

This has some overhead: one vptr in the class itself and a separate dispatch mechanism in the polymorphic value. It also has a pointer like interface instead of a value like.

However, considering how easy it is to use it comparing to writing your own type_erased adapter, I'd say for most use-cases would be more than good enough.