# Aliasing for small buffer optimization with std::aligned_union and std::aligned_union

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

I was looking at implementation small buffer optimization for a `std::function`-like object.

Boost implements the small buffer for `boost::function` like this:

```
union function_buffer
{
    mutable void* obj_ptr;
    struct type_t {
      const detail::sp_typeinfo* type;
      bool const_qualified;
      bool volatile_qualified;
    } type;

    mutable void (*func_ptr)();

    struct bound_memfunc_ptr_t {
      void (X::*memfunc_ptr)(int);
      void* obj_ptr;
    } bound_memfunc_ptr;

    struct obj_ref_t {
      mutable void* obj_ptr;
      bool is_const_qualified;
      bool is_volatile_qualified;
    } obj_ref;

    // To relax aliasing constraints
    mutable char data;
  };
```

and does things like:

```
new (reinterpret_cast<void*>(&out_buffer.data)) functor_type(*in_functor);
```

Moreover C++11 provides, `std::aligned_union` and [`std::aligned_storage` which seems suitable for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582786/easy-way-to-implement-small-buffer-optimization-for-arbitrary-type-erasure-like). The former gives a type:

> suitable for used as uninitialized storage for any object whose
>   size is at most `Len` and whose alignment is a divisor of `Align`

I'd be tempted to use something like:

```
class MyFunction {
private:
  typename std::aligned_storage<something>::type buffer;
  MyFunctionVtable* vtable; 
public:
  template<class F>
  MyFunction(F f)
  {
    static_assert(sizeof(F) <= sizeof(buffer) &&
      alignof(F) <= alignof(buffer), "Type not suitable");
    new (&buffer) F(std::move(f));
    vtable = ...;
  }
  // [...]
};
```

Don't this (or the boost implementation) break the type aliasing rules and why? I'd tend to thinks there are pitfalls which would trigger undefiend behaviour.

For reference, a note in the C++ standard gives an typical implementation of `aligned_storage`:

```
template <std::size_t Len, std::size_t Alignment>
struct aligned_storage {
  typedef struct {
    alignas(Alignment) unsigned char __data[Len];
  } type;
};
```

which looks similar to the boost version in the sens that both rely of `char` to “enable” aliasing.

What about `std::aligned_union<>::type`? Is is safe to use a type which is not explicitly listed?

Comment: `char*` and `void*` can be aliased to other types w/o invoking any kind of UB. And what you are doing is kind of similar to `libstd++` implementation of  SBO for `std::function`. So, both seem to be safe (I would prefer passing a `void*` to `placement new`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a first approximation, aliasing occurs when you write to a storage location with one type and read with another, *and neither of those types are a narrow character type* (`char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`).

The Boost implementation is unsafe if it is at any point writing to `function_buffer` with one member and then reading another member, unless one of those members is `data`. The fact that the `data` member is commented `// To relax aliasing constraints` might indicate that the Boost developers believe that they can trick the compiler into not noticing an aliasing violation.

Your proposed solution of `std::aligned_storage` or `std::aligned_union` is a good one, as long as your `vtable` only reads via the type that was used when writing in your placement-new expression `new (&buffer) F(std::move(f));`, so it's fine to write `reinterpret_cast<F*>(&buffer)` and use the resulting expression as an object of type `F*` pointing to an object of type `F`.

With `std::aligned_union` it's fine to placement-new any type with lesser size and alignment requirements. It would usually be a good idea to make this explicit with a static_assert:

```
static_assert(sizeof(F) <= sizeof(buffer));
static_assert(alignof(F) <= alignof(buffer));
// OK to proceed
new (&buffer) F(std::move(f));
```

Comment: I can't really exploit/cite the relevant part of the C++ to understand/explain what is safe in this regard. I'd tend to thinkg the boost version is as safe as the alingned_storage one.

Comment: @ysdx it depends how you use it. With the boost version you might be tempted to access an inactive member of the union, which would be unsafe.